# A box with no top and a square base

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A box with no top and a square base is to be made by taking a piece of cardboard, cutting equal sized squares from the corners, and folding up each side. Suppose that cardboard piece is square and measures 18 inches on each side.

The Question:
a.) write the function $v(x)$ where v is the volume of thee box and x is the length of the side of a square that was cut from each corner of the cardboard

I already know the answer to the question which is $v(x)=x(18-2x)^2$, but I want to know how to get to the answer (so the process of the problem). I know that you have to subtract the side length of the square from what is given, and that you have to square that to get the length times the width, and then you multiply times x again for the height. But why is it 2x in the parenthesis?

Comment: Draw a diagram...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x$ is the height of the new box. Since you need to fold up 2 sides in each direction then $2x$ is the combined length of those 2 sides and is the amount you need to remove from the length of the initial square to find the length of either side of the new base. Thus, $(18 - 2x)$ is the length of the new base and $(18 - 2x)^2$ is the area of the base. Multiply that by the new height, $x$ to get the volume: $x(18 - 2x)^2$